# Reformat Tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of data which is the output of a net in Tensorflow, however, I want to reformat it into a larger batch size composed of elements of the original tensor. That wasn't very clear, so let's say the output of my net is a tensor with shape (10, 1000, 1) - (batch_size, length, features), and I want to reformat it so that I now have (500, 10, 1) which are 500 vectors of length ten from the original data set.

I am familiar with numpy, so I was just going to use that but you can only use numpy with EagerTensors. I'm not sure if this is an additional problem, but I am attempting a GAN network so the code looks like:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
    generated = generator(noise, training=True)
    generated = reformat(generated)
    fake_output = discriminator(generated, training=True)
    real_output = discriminator(real, training=True)
    gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
    disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(...)
```

I mention this as I am unsure if reformatting the data in this context would mess up the training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `tf.reshape()`? Should work with both eager and graph-based tensors. It's a bit unclear why the total number of elements in your reformatted tensor is less than of the original, but if this is what you really want I suggest using a combination of `tf.reshape()` and generating a list of random indices which you then use to randomly select from the original tensor to achieve the desired number of total elements.

EDIT based on comments:

You essentially specify the portions of the tensor you'd like to sample as the original batch index and the original starting index along length. Let's call these `b` and `s` respectively. So you create random lists of `b` and `s` of length 500, then use these to index your tensor. If `B` and `S` are the lists of length 500 for each of these, your indexing operation might look something like `new_tensor = old_tensor[B,S,:]`. – DerekG 31 mins ago

Indexing (I believe) supports graph computation because the gradient is just a constant for the selected indices. I'm not 100% sure that this will allow for graph-based computation without having to retrace the graph based on the random indices, but if this is the case then I don't think there's a way you can do random subsampling without needing to retrac

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify that last part? I guess my question boils down to how do you/can you create a graph-based tensor that is composed of multiple random sections of another graph-based tensor. As I mentioned in the question, let's say I have a batch with data of length 1000, and I want to create a larger batch by randomly sampling this for data of a smaller length 10. I was getting a little stuck with it since I'm not familiar with the data type.

Comment: So to clarify, you randomly sample vectors of length 10. These are selected from any of the ten original vectors of length 10,000?

Comment: Assuming the above is true, you essentially specify the portions of the tensor you'd like to sample as the original batch index and the original starting index along length. Let's call these `b` and `s` respectively. So you create  random lists of `b` and `s` of length 500, then use these to index your tensor. If `B` and `S` are the lists of length 500 for each of these, your indexing operation might look something like `new_tensor = old_tensor[B,S,:].

Comment: Indexing (I believe) supports graph computation because the gradient is just a constant for the selected indices. I'm not 100% sure that this will allow for graph-based computation without having to retrace the graph based on the random indices, but if this is the case then I don't think there's a way you can do random subsampling without needing to retrace

Comment: Ahh, I think I see what you're saying. Thanks for the help!